# Get grouped data from 2 dataframes with condition

Tags: python, pandas

Have 2 dataframes:

```
print df1

userid  reg_date
1       2015-07-21
2       2015-07-11
3       2015-07-14

print df2

userid           date               status      amount
1             2015-07-22            CHARGED      11.68
1             2015-07-29            CHARGED      21.4
2             2015-07-13            CHARGED      18.98
2             2015-07-15           DECLINED      10.96
```

Need for every userid from df1 find sum(amount)in df2 where status="CHARGED" and reg_date+7>date

```
# result
userid amount
1      11.68
2      18.98
3      0
```

I build solution in such way. 
But in such way if there no rows satisfying condition in df2 nothing will be returned for UserId(need 0 to be returned).

```
    import pandas as pd
    from datetime import timedelta
    df1 = pd.read_csv('Task2_data1.csv', sep=',',parse_dates=['reg_date'])
    df2 = pd.read_csv('Task2_data2.csv', sep=',',parse_dates=['date'])
    df2['amount'] = df2['amount'].replace(',','.', regex=True).astype(float)
    df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', on=['userid', 'userid'])
    df3 = df3[(df3.status == 'CHARGED') & 
              (df3.reg_date + timedelta(days=7)>df3.date)]   
    print df3.groupby(['userid'])['amount'].sum()
```

Is there any other way to make this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
In [4974]: dff = df2.merge(df1)

In [4975]: (dff[dff['status'].eq('CHARGED') & (dff['date']-dff['reg_date']).dt.days.le(7)]
              .groupby('userid')['amount'].sum()
              .reindex(df1['userid'].unique(), fill_value=0)
              .reset_index())
Out[4975]:
   userid  amount
0       1   11.68
1       2   18.98
2       3    0.00
```